# Beautiful Soup only gets header of table

Tags: beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to import the data from a table on this website to a csv:http://www.ameren.com/illinois/residential/supply-choice/renewables/interconnection-queue.

I have tried many different solutions, as posted by users on this forum in the past, but none of them seem to work. I believe it's an issue with the html itself, but I'm wondering if there is a way to address this.

I have also tried the same code with a different website, and it works successfully.

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from pprint import pprint
page = requests.get('http://www.ameren.com/illinois/residential/supply-choice/renewables/interconnection-queue')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html5lib')
table = soup.find("table")
comments = [[td.get_text() for td in row.find_all('td')] for row in table.find_all('tr')]
pprint(comments)
```

The output is as follows: [[]]

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect your browsers Network calls, (in your browser press F12 -> Network tab), you'll see that the page makes a POST request to:

```
https://www.ameren.com/api/ameren/InterConnectReport/InterConnectReportSearchResults
```

[image]

You can mimic the request and get all the data in a `dict` format where you can access the keys/values. In fact, you don't need `BeautifulSoup`, just `requests` is enough:

```py
import requests

data = {
    "draw": "1",
    "columns[0][data]": "projectId",
    "columns[0][name]": "",
    "columns[0][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[0][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[0][search][value]": "",
    "columns[0][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[1][data]": "propertyType",
    "columns[1][name]": "",
    "columns[1][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[1][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[1][search][value]": "",
    "columns[1][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[2][data]": "totalGeneratorRating",
    "columns[2][name]": "",
    "columns[2][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[2][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[2][search][value]": "",
    "columns[2][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[3][data]": "currentStatus",
    "columns[3][name]": "",
    "columns[3][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[3][orderable]": "false",
    "columns[3][search][value]": "",
    "columns[3][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[4][data]": "substationId",
    "columns[4][name]": "",
    "columns[4][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[4][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[4][search][value]": "",
    "columns[4][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[5][data]": "subQueue",
    "columns[5][name]": "",
    "columns[5][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[5][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[5][search][value]": "",
    "columns[5][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[6][data]": "feederId",
    "columns[6][name]": "",
    "columns[6][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[6][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[6][search][value]": "",
    "columns[6][search][regex]": "false",
    "columns[7][data]": "feederQueue",
    "columns[7][name]": "",
    "columns[7][searchable]": "true",
    "columns[7][orderable]": "true",
    "columns[7][search][value]": "",
    "columns[7][search][regex]": "false",
    "order[0][column]": "0",
    "order[0][dir]": "asc",
    "start": "0",
    "length": "25",
    "search[value]": "",
    "search[regex]": "false",
    "ProjectId": "",
    "PropertyType": "",
    "Substation": "",
    "Feeder": "",
}

response = requests.post(
    "https://www.ameren.com/api/ameren/InterConnectReport/InterConnectReportSearchResults",
    data=data,
).json()


fmt_string = "{:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20} {:<20}"

columns = [x["data"] for x in response["columns"]]

print(fmt_string.format(*columns))

for data in response["data"]:
    print(
        fmt_string.format(
            data["projectId"],
            data["propertyType"],
            data["totalGeneratorRating"],
            data["currentStatus"],
            data["substationId"],
            data["subQueue"],
            data["feederId"],
            data["feederQueue"],
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
projectId            propertyType         totalGeneratorRating currentStatus        substationId         subQueue             feederId             feederQueue         
DER-04311            Level 2              0.2                  Construction         146195               1                    A27011               1                   
DER-05094            Level 2              1.14                 Construction         975902               2                    M07235               1                   
DER-06422            Level 2              2.0                  Construction         322219               2                    Q10702               1                   
DER-06608            Level 2              2.0                  Construction         565083               3                    B19001               1                   
DER-06609            Level 2              2.0                  Construction         458366               2                    C00001               1                   
DER-06709            Level 2              1.25                 Witness Test         520122               1                    B68003               1                   
DER-06784            Level 2              0.5                  Witness Test         771055               2                    Q85162               1                   
DER-06786            Level 2              0.5                  Witness Test         890156               2                    L80221               1                   
DER-06837            Level 2              2.0                  Construction         674509               3                    N60172               1                   
DER-06866            Level 4              5.0                  Construction         765864               1                    C76002               1                   
DER-06868            Level 4              5.0                  Construction         505417               2                    J39392               1                   
DER-06876            Level 4              5.0                  Construction         911349               1                    Y89540               1                   
DER-06986            Level 2              1.95                 Construction         469483               1                    M05368               1                   
DER-06998            Level 2              2.0                  Construction         505417               3                    J58380               1
```